# SSH.NET connection aborts when executing a command that takes long time to finish

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, ssh.net

Error in SSH.NET, when I am trying to run a command which usually takes more than 30 mins to complete:

> Error source:SSH Run Command . Error message:An established connection was aborted by the server.

I could replicate the issue with simple `sleep 100m` command passed to SSH.NET. Same error appears.

Is there any time out that we can set to keep the session alive for 100 mins or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `SshClient.KeepAliveInterval`:

```
client.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
```